# Android Camera output using ndk-blurry result

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-camera

http://postimg.org/image/btd4u4esx/

Hi,

This is the output image(black keyboard with white background) of a code that i modified from one of android samples. I want to take byte data from java file and send it to cpp using jni as unsigned character and and i am trying to display the video frames i receive using open cv mat.

JAVA CODE:

```
native int Fibonacci( byte[] n,int width, int height );
        static {
               System.loadLibrary( "CopyofHDRViewFinder" );
           }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // y = 0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b

            Log.v(TAG, "enter in imageSaver! Format is: " + mImage.getFormat());
            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            int heigth=mImage.getHeight();
            int width=mImage.getWidth();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];            

            buffer.get(bytes);

            int a=Fibonacci(bytes,width,heigth);
            int pixelsize=mImage.getWidth()*mImage.getHeight();
            System.out.println("framewidth:"+mImage.getWidth());
            System.out.println("frameheight:"+mImage.getHeight());
            System.out.println("totalnumberofpixels:"+pixelsize);
            System.out.println("lastpixelvalue:"+a);
```

then the CPP code:(jni)

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_android_hdrviewfinder_HdrViewfinderActivity3_00024ImageSaver_Fibonacci
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray array, jint width, jint height)
{
    i=i+1;
     int len = env->GetArrayLength (array);
        unsigned char* img = new unsigned char[len];
        env->GetByteArrayRegion (array, 0, len-1, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(img));
        const cv::Mat hdrimg(height,width, CV_8UC1, img);
        char buffer[50];
        int ab=sprintf(buffer,"/storage/emulated/0/Android/IMAGE%d.jpg",i);
        cv::imwrite(buffer, hdrimg);
        /*cv::namedWindow("HDRImage");
        cv::imshow("HDRImage", hdrimg);
        cv::waitKey(0);*/
        printf("\n %d", width);
        printf("\n %d", height);
        int a;
        for(int i=0;i<width*height;i++)
        {
           a=(int)img[i];
        }
        int c=width*height;
        return a;
}
```

This returns proper pixel values from 0 to 255. my issue is not that. when i check the image it looks blurry and totally horrible, but still i cant deduce that its a keyboard slightly. Anyone has seen similar results? Help, if you can..